# To highlight list-item text-color

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I have 2 components called `list` and `details` which i placed inside another component called `customer` which looks like this:

[image]

**Scenario:** By default 1st list-item (i,e customer-one) is selected means its `background-color` is highlighted as shown in the image.When i click the next item( say custome-two) that item will be highlighted.

**Here the issue is:** I want to highlight the `text-color` too..:) I tried giving for ex: **(color:red!important;)**. still no result.

Here is the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-bolnqz?file=app/list/list.component.scss)

Comment: Please include code here too

Comment: since the components are more i have given `stackblitz` link. @Justcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
.selected span{
          color:red!important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.selected span{
    color:red!important;
}
```

This will work for sure, since the text is inside the span.

Comment: You do not need to apply `!important` it will work without it.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer was solved before, but you should try to not use !important.
Here is the code without !important flag:

```
.selected span{
          color:red;
    }
```